# Springboot app failing to start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

My springboot application is not starting. The eclipse console is not giving any hint. Earlier it used to start, but now its screwed up. Also, my colleague have almost identical workspace. And it app starts on his machine. Is anyone able to spot anything in this eclipse log:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/593932/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/593932/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
2017-07-21 17:22:26.612 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration,class org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration,class org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration,class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration,class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration,class org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration,class org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration
2017-07-21 17:22:26.734 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Activated profiles dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:26.735 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/C:/Mahesh/workspaces/xyzws8/blueprint-graph/target/classes/bootstrap.properties' (classpath:/bootstrap.properties)
2017-07-21 17:22:26.735 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'file:/C:/Mahesh/workspaces/xyzws8/blueprint-graph/target/classes/bootstrap.properties' (classpath:/bootstrap.properties) for profile dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:26.741  INFO 7316 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2118cddf: startup date [Fri Jul 21 17:22:26 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-07-21 17:22:27.501  INFO 7316 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-07-21 17:22:27.633  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7474b600] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:28.183 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration#configServicePropertySource matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.RetryConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.retry.annotation.Retryable' (OnClassCondition)

   DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled) did not find property 'spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator'; @ConditionalOnMissingClass did not find unwanted class (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None




  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.3.RELEASE)

2017-07-21 17:22:28.874  INFO 7316 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888
2017-07-21 17:22:30.026  WARN 7316 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/pqr/dev3": Connection refused: connect; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
2017-07-21 17:22:30.029  INFO 7316 --- [           main] com.abc.xyz.pqr.pqrApplication    : The following profiles are active: dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:30.033 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.abc.xyz.pqr.pqrApplication
2017-07-21 17:22:30.056 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Activated profiles dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:30.057 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'jar:file:/C:/Users/593932/.m2/repository/com/abc/xyz/utils/logger/2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/logger-2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2017-07-21 17:22:30.057 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:/C:/Mahesh/workspaces/xyzws8/pqr-rest/target/classes/application-dev3.properties' (classpath:/application-dev3.properties)
2017-07-21 17:22:30.057 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'file:/C:/Mahesh/workspaces/xyzws8/pqr-rest/target/classes/application-dev3.properties' (classpath:/application-dev3.properties) for profile dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:30.057 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped (empty) config file 'jar:file:/C:/Users/593932/.m2/repository/com/abc/xyz/utils/logger/2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/logger-2.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties) for profile dev3
2017-07-21 17:22:30.057  INFO 7316 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@590c73d3: startup date [Fri Jul 21 17:22:30 IST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2118cddf
2017-07-21 17:22:30.061 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@590c73d3: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6c67e137: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,pqrApplication]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5afa3c9
2017-07-21 17:22:54.813  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2017-07-21 17:22:56.472  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=913a3bd9-b3c0-3356-9fa2-16200e317e2e
2017-07-21 17:22:56.572  INFO 7316 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-07-21 17:22:56.727  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'com.abc.xyz.workitem.client.WorkItemClient' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClientFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:57.254  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$585ab303] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:57.706  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration' of type [org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7a847922] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:57.946  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsInterceptorConfiguration$MetricsRestTemplateConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a875944] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:57.998  INFO 7316 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7474b600] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-07-21 17:22:58.013 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@2589d787]
2017-07-21 17:22:58.013 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@1788cb61]
2017-07-21 17:22:59.563 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\593932\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
2017-07-21 17:22:59.564 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: C:\Users\593932\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\1.5.3.RELEASE\spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar
2017-07-21 17:22:59.564 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Document root: C:\Mahesh\workspaces\xyzws8\pqr-rest\src\main\webapp
2017-07-21 17:22:59.685  INFO 7316 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 0 (http)
Jul 21, 2017 5:22:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 21, 2017 5:22:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
Jul 21, 2017 5:23:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-07-21 17:23:02.138  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 32081 ms
2017-07-21 17:23:02.513 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Added existing Servlet initializer bean 'dispatcherServletRegistration'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration$DispatcherServletRegistrationConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'metricsFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'characterEncodingFilter'; order=-2147483648, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'; order=-10000, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'httpPutFormContentFilter'; order=-9900, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'requestContextFilter'; order=-105, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.639 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'webRequestLoggingFilter'; order=2147483637, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/TraceWebFilterAutoConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.640 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.s.ServletContextInitializerBeans : Created Filter initializer for bean 'applicationContextIdFilter'; order=2147483647, resource=class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration.class]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.674  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.700  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'metricsFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.701  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.720  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.721  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.721  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.721  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.721  INFO 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2017-07-21 17:23:03.913 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Initializing filter 'requestContextFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.916 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.917 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Initializing filter 'applicationContextIdFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.917 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Filter 'applicationContextIdFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.917 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.w.f.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Initializing filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.917 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.w.f.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Initializing filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:03.918 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Initializing filter 'metricsFilter'
2017-07-21 17:23:03.919 DEBUG 7316 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Filter 'metricsFilter' configured successfully
2017-07-21 17:23:06.527 DEBUG 7316 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.AutoConfigurationPackages        : @EnableAutoConfiguration was declared on a class in the package 'com.abc.xyz,com.abc.xyz.pqr'. Automatic @Repository and @Entity scanning is enabled.
2017-07-21 17:23:08.193  INFO 7316 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-21 17:23:08.608  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-07-21 17:23:10.167  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-07-21 17:23:10.180  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
2017-07-21 17:23:10.181  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-07-21 17:23:10.602  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-07-21 17:23:11.278  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: com.abc.xyz.hibernate.dialect.JSONBPostgreSQLDialect
2017-07-21 17:23:11.355  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
2017-07-21 17:23:11.361  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@18811c42
2017-07-21 17:23:12.153  WARN 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator        : HHH000409: Using org.hibernate.id.UUIDHexGenerator which does not generate IETF RFC 4122 compliant UUID values; consider using org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator instead
2017-07-21 17:23:13.606  INFO 7316 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2017-07-21 17:23:15.246  INFO 7316 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-07-21 17:23:15.326  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy          : Final method [protected final void org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.setRegisterErrorPageFilter(boolean)] cannot get proxied via CGLIB: Calls to this method will NOT be routed to the target instance and might lead to NPEs against uninitialized fields in the proxy instance.
2017-07-21 17:23:15.908  INFO 7316 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@691eb389: startup date [Fri Jul 21 17:23:15 IST 2017]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@590c73d3
2017-07-21 17:23:16.015  INFO 7316 --- [           main] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Jul 21, 2017 5:23:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
```

Is this line an issue?:

```
2017-07-21 17:23:11.355  INFO 7316 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
```

Earlier I used to get following:

```
 2017-07-21 16:43:44.438  INFO 7008 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

So I added

```
hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

to properties file.

Notice that the tomcat stops abruptly (last two lines):

```
Jul 21, 2017 5:23:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Tomcat
```

Sorry for putting so much log. I put `--debug` in programs arguments. Is there anything else I can do to get some more information?

Here are some files as requested in comments:

- [pom file](https://docs.zoho.com/file/3kn0gc2667e9369504ce79800e551e03bfa3d)
- [main class file](https://docs.zoho.com/file/3kn0g2abc3439b6f247b5943138eb18a9fdd8)

Note that I have other applications as dependencies. So they will also be adding many other dependencies which are not getting captured in above pom. How can I share them here?

The main class is really a placeholder which triggers SpringBoot which in turn runs various stuff say load beans, run apache camel routes etc.

Comment: could you share the class where the main method is and also the `pom.xml`?

Comment: As Cahen said pls share the pom.xml,configuration class if exists and main class .Before do mvn clean install if you using maven with spring boot

Comment: My guess would be eclipse is mucking with the classpath, and causing issues.  Can you get it to start directly from the console?

Comment: Added files and edited question

Comment: Try to use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=slf4j`